# How Clang generates code for function parameters?

Tags: llvm, static-analysis, callstack, llvm-ir

In a function , I want to know how the parameters is passed into the function body, so that to track the flow of the parameters. I tried a simple code, and find there seems to be an `alloc`-`store` pattern for every parameter, I wonder whether it is true or not?

A demo code is

```
int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

The llvm ir it generated is:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @add(i32 %x, i32 %y) #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 %y, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %5 = add nsw i32 %3, %4
  ret i32 %5
}
```

In the example we can see that,

1. For every parameters, the Clang use a `alloc` instruction to define a
       local variable
2. Following the `alloc` instruction, `store` instructions is used to
       assign values?

My questions are:

1. Is all the function LLVM IR are generated in this `alloc` and `store` patterns? Or what exactly LLVM do with the parameters?
2. The order of `parameters` is determined by the convention it used?

Comment: minor comment: you seem to be asking how clang generates LLVM IR, not how LLVM generates code.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Thanks for your comment, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this pattern holds for code that has no compile-time optimizations; however, if you instead compile the code with -O3 (or anything that applies the mem2reg optimization), this pattern is optimized out:

(clang -emit-llvm -S -O0 add.c)

```
define i32 @add(i32 %x, i32 %y) #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 %y, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %5 = add nsw i32 %3, %4
  ret i32 %5
}
```

(opt -mem2reg add.ll -o add_m.ll)

```
define i32 @add(i32 %x, i32 %y) #0 {
  %1 = add nsw i32 %y, %x
  ret i32 %1
}
```

So if you are controlling all of the code that you are analyzing, then you can rely on this pattern.  I would instead recommend that you use the LLVM APIs to get the function arguments.  The following code iterates through the arguments to a function F and prints them after casting to values.

```
for (auto AI = F->arg_begin(), AE = F->arg_end(); AI != AE; ++AI)
{
    Value* v = &*AI;
    errs() << *v << "\n";
}
```

The values in the above sample are usable in the same way as any other value in the IR.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I tried the as you indicated, but it prints like `i32 %x`. I am wondering how to test if two values are equal, for example, in Binary file, each pointer stores an address it points to.

Comment: That is a different question.  Having retrieved the Value* for each function argument, you are then capable of using it for further analysis.  That could be static as originally tagged, in which case you may need to construct a control flow graph and the usage of variables through each function.  Dynamically, you could check equality by adding additional IR that checks the values on entry, either by constructing the comparisons in place or passing the values to separate support routines.

My example was meant to show a simple way to initially access the values and do something with them.

Comment: Thanks for the nice guidance.